# Split string into array of chars

Tags: c++, string, split

I'm writing a program that requires a string to be inputted, then broken up into individual letters. Essentially, I need help finding a way to turn "string" into `["s","t","r","i","n","g"]`. The strings are also stored using the string data type instead of just an array of chars by default. I would like to keep it that way and avoid char but will use it if necessary.

Comment: Do you need to do something to the letters after it's split? That is, you need to put the letters into some kind of data structure other than the `string`?

Comment: This is a silly question, a string is an array of chars.

Comment: Thanks for the question, the answer helped me, I know it's obvious but I was stuck.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
string a = "hello"; 
cout << a[1];
```

I hope that explains it

Comment: i don't feel like it as i'm not here to give tutorials, just answers.

Comment: For the record, you can also just do: cout << "hello"[1];

Comment: @AshleysBrain: Or cout << 1["hello"];

Answer (score 34):

Assuming you already have the string inputted:

```
string s("string");
vector<char> v(s.begin(), s.end());
```

This will fill the vector `v` with the characters from a string.

Comment: Best solution I've seen! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

A string is just a sequence of the underlying character (i.e. char for std::string and wchar_t for std::wstring).

Because of that, you easily get each letter:

```
for (std::string::size_type l = 0; l < str.length(); ++l)
{
    std::string::value_type c = str[l];
}
```

Comment: You're::gonna::scare::him::with::all::that::stuff. imo using `int` or, even better, `size_t` will work on every existing platform and it's way more clear.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `c_str()` method of `std::string`:

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
  string text = "hello";
  size_t length = text.length() + sizeof('\0');
  char * letters = new char[length];
  strcpy(letters, length.c_str());
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < length; ++i)
  {
      cout << '[' << i << "] == '" << letters[i] << "'\n";
  }
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Adding sizeof('\0') to length isnt needed because it may be more than 1 and then the allocated array will have a higher size than needed. Adding 1 instead of sizeof('\0') is better.

Comment: George, sizeof(char) is _always_ 1.

Comment: Not true! sizeof(char) is not *always* 1. I worked with a DSP chip where *everything* was at least 32-bit, char, short, int -- sizeof(char) == sizeof(short) == sizeof(int). The C standard just says that sizeof(char) <= sizeof(short) <= sizeof(int) but does not require sizeof(char) == 1. One of the side effects was that casting to char and BYTE to limit values to 8-bits had no effect since the data type was natively 32-bit. Granted this was an unusual architecture, but the C standard definitely does not say sizeof(char) == 1.

Comment: No, @Ryan, I'm sorry but you're wrong. Section 5.3.3 "Sizeof" states: "sizeof(char), sizeof(signed char) and sizeof(unsigned char) are 1". A char is a byte but neither is necessarily an octet (8 bits). This is the same as with C. This is from the n3000 draft of C++0x but it's been that way for ages.

Comment: Ah, I stand corrected. My real point was do *not* assume 1 == 8 bits which you clearly state. The interesting thing about the DSP chip was 1 == sizeof(char) == sizeof(short) == sizeof(int) which surprised me when I found that out where 1 == 32 bits.

Comment: Yeah, Ryan, that actually bit me once. I thought I'd found a discrepancy in the ISO C standard since they talked about a char being allowed to be more than 8 bits yet sizeof returned the number of bytes (but still one for char). Turns out ISO had redefined byte as well (which makes sense, all other standards, like their comms ones, use octet for an 8-bit value).

Answer (score 0):

```
string input ="some string for example my cat is handsome";
vector<string> split_char_to_vector(string input) {
  vector<string> output;
  for(size_t i=0;i<=input.length();i++) {
    output.push_back(input[i]));
  }
  return output;
}
```

if you want to convert split strings into character the first traverse the string  and write for each characters of string to the i'th position of char array ie

```
 char array[1000];
std::string input="i dont think love never ends";
 for(size_t i=0;i<=input.length();/*or string::npos;*/i++)
  {
            if (input[i] != '\0')
        {
            array[i] = input[i];
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        std::cout << array[i] << std::endl;
    }
```

Comment: Add the details also to make answer understandable.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may answer the question, it is better to include some context, explaining how it works and when to use it. Code-only answers tend to be less useful in the long run. See [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for some more info.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to convert split strings into character the first traverse the string and write for each characters of string to the i'th position of char array ie

```
  char array[1000];
   std::string input="i dont think love never ends";
   for(size_t i=0;i<=input.length();/*or string::npos;*/i++)
    {
        if (input[i] != '\0')
        {
        array[i] = input[i];
        }
    else
        {
        break;
        }
    }
    //to avoid noise after position input.length();
        for (size_t i = input.length(); i <= 1000; i++)
        {
             array[i] = '\0';
        }
      //ie return array; or print
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
    std::cout << array[i] << std::endl;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a for loop to iterate through the characters of a string.

```
    std::string str = "word"
    for(char i : str){
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
    }
```